# CharacterAtIndex in Swift

Tags: objective-c, arrays, swift

I am trying to go back and forth with different simple objective-c projects and port them to swift.

In objective-c, I have the following loop.

```
NSCountedSet *firstSet = [[NSCountedSet alloc] init];
NSCountedSet *secondSet = [[NSCountedSet alloc] init];
for(int i = 0; i < firstString.length; i++) {
    [firstSet addObject:@([firstString characterAtIndex:i])];
    [secondSet addObject:@([theSecondString characterAtIndex:i])];
}
```

I am attempting to port it to swift, but cannot figure out the addObject methodology

```
  let firstSet = NSCountedSet()
  let secondSet = NSCountedSet()
  let lengthOfFirstString = firstString.utf16Count  
  for var i = 0; i < lengthOfFirstString; i++ {

  }
```

Help on this would be appreciated

Comment: Don't remove your question contents. It is not only for you personally but also for future readers of this thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not pretty, but here goes:

```
let firstSet = NSCountedSet()
let secondSet = NSCountedSet()
let lengthOfFirstString = firstString.utf16Count
for var i = 0; i < lengthOfFirstString; i++ {
    firstString[advance(firstString.startIndex, i)]
    theSecondString[advance(theSecondString.startIndex, i)]
}
```

Swift will hopefully include better functionality for substrings in future versions.

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following code:

```
let firstSet = NSCountedSet()
let secondSet = NSCountedSet()
let lengthOfFirstString = firstString.utf16Count
for var i = 0; i < lengthOfFirstString; i++ {
    firstSet.addObject(@[firstString[i]])
    secondSet.addObject(@[secondString[i]])
}
```